# Any purpose to add #[transactional] attribute to an extrinsic?

Tags: pallet, extrinsic, transactional

Could you help me to understand if there is any special purpose to add a `#[transactional]` attribute to an extrinsic?

For instance, in `pallet-uniques` there is a call `buy_item` tagged with `frame_support::transactional` attribute: [github.com/parity/substrate/frame/uniques/src/lib.rs#L1526](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/7a64651e0ec6823cc2773f5b4823f56943d2d076/frame/uniques/src/lib.rs#L1526).

Aren't all the functions under `#[pallet::call]` transactional by default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that's a history code.

All the calls are transactional by default in the latest Substrate version.

Answer (score 5):

Yes the extrinsics are transactional by default. In fact, if you need to make them non transactional you'd need to mark them accordingly as explained [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/5836/318). The transactional tag is just a legacy thing remained from when it wasn't the default behavior.